# Variables de entorno

Tags: python, python-2.7, variables, raspberry-pi, variables-globales

Necesito crear una variable de entorno para compartir información entre dos scripts Python.

Me explico, tengo creados tres scripts en Python para comprobar el funcionamiento o más bien verificar que se crea la variable de entorno. Estos archivos son:

blink.py

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time, os,sys
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(7, GPIO.OUT)

repeticion = 0
try:
    #os.system('export CONTADOR = "0"')
    os.environ["CONTADOR"] = str(repeticion)
except:
    print sys.exc_info()[0]

def blink():
    if os.path.isfile("stop_blink"):
        os.system("sudo rm stop_blink")
    print "Ejecucion iniciada..."
    global repeticion
    while not os.path.isfile("stop_blink"):
        GPIO.output(7, True) # Enciende el 7
        time.sleep(0.5) # Espera 1/2 segundo
        GPIO.output(7, False) # Apaga el 7
        time.sleep(0.5) # Espera 1/2 segundo
        if (repeticion>= 10000):
            repeticion= 0
        repeticion= repeticion+ 1
        print ("Vuelta " + str(repeticion))
        try:
            print ("Contador {}".format(os.environ.get("CONTADOR","No Funciona")))
        except:
            print sys.exc_info()[0]
        try:
            print ("El valor de cuenta es: {}".format(os.environ["CONTADOR"]))
        except:
            print sys.exc_info()[0]
        try:
            os.environ["CONTADOR"] = str(repeticion)
            #os.system('export CONTADOR = ' +str(repeticion))
        except:
            print sys.exc_info()[0]
    print "Ejecucion finalizada"
    os.environ["CONTADOR"] = "0"
    GPIO.cleanup() #limpieza de los GPIO

blink() #llamada a la funcion blink
```

consulta.py

```
    #!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import os, sys

try:
    print ("1.- Contador {}".format(os.environ.get("CONTADOR","No Funciona")))
except:
    print "1.1.- ", sys.exc_info()[0]
try:
    print ("2.- El valor de cuenta es: {}".format(os.environ["CONTADOR"]))
except:
    print "2.1.- ", sys.exc_info()[0]

try:
    print ("3.- El valor de cuenta es: {}".format(os.environ.get("CONTADOR","No Funciona")))
except:
    print "3.1.- ", sys.exc_info()[0]
try:
    print ("4.- El valor de cuenta es: {}".format(os.getenv("CONTADOR")))
except:
    print "4.1.- ", sys.exc_info()[0]


if ("CONTADOR" in os.environ):
    print "Existe en 2.7"
if (os.environ.has_key("CONTADOR")):
    print "Existe en 3.1"

for param in os.environ.keys():
    print("%s: %s " % (param, os.environ[param])
```

parar_blink.py

```
    #!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import os

print ("Creando archivo stop_blink")
fichero = open ( 'stop_blink', 'w' ) 
fichero.write('Archivo de parada de blink') 
fichero.close()
print ("Archivo stop_blink creado")
```

El funcionamiento teórico es:

1. El script parar_blink.py crea un archivo llamado stop_blink que de
   ser encontrado por el script blink.py este saldrá del bucle.
2. El script blink.py crea una variable de entorno llamada CONTADOR y
   entra en un bucle que únicamente se detiene cuando exista el archivo
   stop_blink.
   Lo único que hace este script es activar y desactivar una salida cada 1/2 
   segundo y actualizar la variable de entorno con un valor que es el número de 
   repeticiones del bucle.
3. El cript consulta.py cuando se lanza debe leer la variable de entorno 
   CONTADOR e imprimir su valor (en el ejemplo, posteriormente se usará para 
   realizar acciones).
   Todo el código de este script son simplemente diferentes formas de capturar 
   dicha variable y mostrar el resultado.
   El for final lo que hace es mostrar todas las variables actuales.

De la forma que está desarrollado, el script blink.py crea correctamente la variable de entorno y la actualiza, pero al haber sido creada desde el script, el alcance de la misma es únicamente para el proceso actual y sus subprocesos, con lo que al lanzar el script consulta.py no encuentra esta variable.

Lo correcto sería que esta variable se crease en el `/etc/profile` que según entiendo, se ejecuta al inicio del sistema independientemente del usuario, o en el `~/.bash_profile` que es el siguiente en ser ejecutado o si no existiese seguiría por `~/.bash_login` y `~/.profile` siguiendo este orden y ejecutando las órdenes del primero que se encuentre y sea legible.

El problema es que lo he intentado con todos, y en ninguno el script consulta.py encuentra que se haya creado la variable de entorno, ni siquiera al incluirlo en `~/.bashrc` que sería el shell específico del usuario actual.

He intentado escribiendo la variable según los ejemplos que he encontrado Googleando:

Modo a):

```
CONTADOR = "XX"
export CONTADOR
```

Modo b):

```
export CONTADOR = "XX"
```

Modo c:)

```
echo "export AS='name'" >> ~/.bash_profile
```

En todos los caso he probado con y sin `source ~/.bash_profile` después de la variable para actualizar el shell.

Se me ocurre una alternativa al uso de la variable de entorno y es crear un archivo de texto por ejemplo en el que se vaya actualizando el valor deseado y al que acceda el otro script para recoger dicho valor, pero esta opción no me parece la más "decente", y pienso que consumiría muchos más recursos que usar una variable.

¿Alguna sugerencia?, ¿Estoy intentando cargar la variable en el lugar erróneo o de forma incorrecta?, ¿Existe alguna otra alternativa para realizar esta acción, tal vez los dos scripts pueden compartir datos mientras se ejecutan en hilos diferentes (yo lo desconozco)?

O tal vez debería plantearlo con otro enfoque. Me explico:

Lo que pretendo hacer es tener un script Python funcionando en un bucle contínuo tomando una serie de medidas de sensores conectados a pines de la Raspberry y en función de estos sensores, y de otros parámetros, se realiza una determinada de acciones sobre periféricos conectados a otros pines (es decir, activar salidas).

El inconveniente lo tengo cuando tengo que tomar valores de medidas que está manejando este script para que otro script realice su trabajo, además necesito pasarle una serie de valores arbitrarios al script principal (introducidos bien por el usuario, bien por otro script).

Yo había pensado que la forma más eficiente eran las variables de entorno, pero agradecería cualquier otro enfoque que pueda dar un poco de luz a este agujero negro en el que estoy metido. Lo cierto es que desconozco si es posible y/o viable que estos scripts se engloben en módulos para que trabajen desde el mismo hilo padre, aunque aún así se me queda atrás la entrada del usuario, lógicamente el script no puede pararse a esperar al usuario, sino que debe ser una interrupción o algo así ya que este valor no es constante.

Answer (score 1):

No veo la necesidad de ejecutar el `blink` y el `consulta` en dos procesos separados. Ambos podrían ser dos hilos de un mismo proceso, uno ejecutando la función `blink()` y el otro ejecutando otra función (a programar) que podríamos llamar `consultar()`.

El tener dos hilos te permite que la ejecución de esas dos funciones ocurra en paralelo, pero al estar dentro del mismo proceso podrías compartir variables globales, lo que te evitará el lío de la variable de entorno.

### Primera versión, fácil, contiene un bug

La primera idea sería por tanto la siguiente: hacer que el `contador` sea una variable global, que el hilo `blink()` va incrementando mientras el hilo `consultar()` la va leyendo, por ejemplo cada 5 segundos. También hago una variable global `parar` que ambos hilos consultan para saber cuándo salir del bucle (y la cambia el hilo `blink()` cuando detecta el archivo apropiado).

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time, os,sys
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(7, GPIO.OUT)

contador = 0
parar = False

def blink():
    global contador
    global parar

    if os.path.isfile("stop_blink"):
        os.system("sudo rm stop_blink")
        parar = False
    print("Ejecucion iniciada...")

    while not parar:
        parar = os.path.isfile("stop_blink")
        GPIO.output(7, True) # Enciende el 7
        time.sleep(0.5) # Espera 1/2 segundo
        GPIO.output(7, False) # Apaga el 7
        time.sleep(0.5) # Espera 1/2 segundo
        contador = (contador + 1) % 10000
        print ("Vuelta " + str(contador))
    print("Ejecucion finalizada")
    contador = 0
    GPIO.cleanup() #limpieza de los GPIO

def consultar():
    global contador
    global parar
    while not parar:
        time.sleep(5)  # Esperar 5 segundos
        print("El valor de cuenta es: {}".format(contador))

# Función principal que arranca ambos hilos
import threading
hilo_blink = threading.Thread(target = blink)
hilo_consultar = threading.Thread(target = consultar)

hilo_blink.start()
hilo_consultar.start()
```

Te recomiendo que uses python3 para ejecutar este programa, ya que python2 no permite parar su ejecución con Ctrl-C por ser multihilo (necesitarías matar el proceso con `kill`), mientras que en python3 ese aspecto se ha corregido.

Pero como anuncio en el título, esta solución tiene un *bug*. ¿Cuál es? La programación multihilo es delicada cuando los hilos comparten información a través de variables globales, como es este caso. Ya que cada hilo se ejecuta de forma independiente y a la vez, pudiera darse el caso de que ambos hilos intenten acceder a la vez a la variable global. En algunos casos esto puede causar un problema, sobre todo si ambos hilos intentan modificar esa variable.

Piensa por ejemplo que dos hilos intentan incrementar el contador a la vez. Puesto que para modificar el contador primero se lee, luego se calcula su nuevo valor y luego se escribe el resultado en memoria, si en el tiempo entre que entre leemos y escribimos otro hilo también la lee, la incrementa y la escribe, nuestra posterior escritura podría sobreescribir el resultado del otro hilo. Así la variable en lugar de quedar incrementada en 2 (una vez por cada hilo), quedaría incrementada solo en 1.

En tu caso no hay ese problema porque un hilo sólo lee, mientras otro sólo escribe. No obstante, si quieres hacerlo bien, el código se complica. El contador ya no podría ser un simple entero, sino que necesitaría ser un objeto con métodos `incrementar()` y `obtener_valor()`, y estos métodos deberían incluir cerrojos (*locks*) para evitar que dos hilos intenten entrar a la vez en esos métodos.

### Solución buena, con cerrojos

Un contador "robusto" frente a estos problemas podría ser el siguiente:

```
class Contador:
    def __init__(self, inicial=0, reiniciar_con = 10000):
        self.valor = inicial
        self.reiniciar_con = reiniciar_con
        self._cerrojo = threading.Lock()

    def incrementar(self):
        with self._cerrojo:
            self.valor = (self.valor + 1) % self.reiniciar_con
        return self.valor

    def obtener_valor(self):
        with self._cerrojo:
            return self.valor
```

Ahora la variable global ya no sería `contador = 0`, sino:

```
contador = Contador()
```

Para incrementarlo desde `blink()` bastará hacer:

```
contador.incrementar()
```

Y para consultarlo para imprimir:

```
print("El valor de cuenta es: {}".format(contador.obtener_valor()))
```

Comment: Todo lo veo más o menos claro para hacerlo de ese modo que sugieres, entiendo que cada función debería ejecutarse en un hilo diferente, pero sigo sin ver la forma de recibir los datos o comandos externos, si dejar una función "a la escucha" sería adecuado (Tengo que indagar más sobre este punto, creo haber leído que puede quedar a la espera de la entrada y no influir en los otros hilos, pero no lo tengo claro, igual que tampoco sé cual sería el nivel de sobrecarga sobre la memoria y la CPU.

Comment: La idea final, por si sirve de aclaración, es que cuando haya verificado y decidido la forma adecuada, poder crear un script que se ejecute en segundo plano y que recoja información de varios sensores conectados a la GPIO, a su vez realice una serie de cálculos y ejecute determinadas actuaciones sobre otras salidas de la GPIO, al mismo tiempo que toda la información pueda ser visualizada a través de un servidor Apache instalado en la misma Raspberry, y que a su vez, a través de la propia página se le pueda enviar comandos para activar salida y cambiar valores de cálculo.

Comment: Lo de la entrada de datos de Usuario es en previsión de realizar una interfaz para el manejo de estos scripts accesible desde el modo gráfico de Raspbian.

Comment: Toda esta parafernalia ya está solucionada en WebIOPi, y de hecho, tengo los scripts que leen, calculan y ejecutan, y que se pueden comandar vía web. El inconveniente es que WebIOPi consume muchos recursos y la Raspberry se cuelga a cada momento, así que, una vez vistas las alternativas, pensaba que lo mejor sería crearlo todo desde cero y de esta forma ahorrarme los módulos intermedios y genéricos que tienen WebIOPi, WiringPi, etc (por ejemplo sus módulos de lectura de sensores, GPIO, LCD, etc) y hacer una solución liviana y ajustada al uso específico.